# sorting ngram word using awk

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I have the following and would like to sort using awk command

```
 capital of the country
 capital of 
 capital 
 capital of the 
 capital is 
 capital is the   
 capital is the like
```

I would like these to be sorted like

```
 capital
 capital is
 capital of
 capital is the 
 capital is the like
 capital of the 
 capital of the country
```

Is it possible to sort exactly same as the above using awk command or should I need to handle it by programming?

Comment: Could you define the order that you have pasted? On what basis the sorting happened

Comment: Is there a typo with the 'capitial' lines? They confuse the alpha sort. It seems like you actually want lines in sorted heap order.

Comment: sorry, yes its typo with capital lines. Is there way I can sort this using awk command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy in Python:

```
import sys

# get input filename from command line
_, infile = sys.argv

# read the data in to a list
with open(infile, "rt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# define a function to use for sorting
def ngram_key(line):
    words = line.split()
    # We want to sort by, first, number of words; second, the text.
    # Return a tuple with two values, number of words and the text.
    return (len(words), line) # same number of words should sort together

# sort the lines using the desired rule
lines.sort(key=ngram_key)

# print the lines to standard output
print(''.join(lines))
```

But AWK doesn't have the `key=` feature of the Python sort.  If Python will work for you, this answer will work.  If you really need AWK, then I recommend using DSU (Decorate, Sort, Undecorate).  Store the lines in an array, but prefix each line with the number of words (as a fixed-length string).  Then all the lines with the same number of words will sort together, just as in the Python program.  Once the sort is done, strip off the fixed-length number and you have your sorted list.  DSU is also called a "Schwartzian Transform".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

So here is a working solution in AWK using the above technique:

```
{
    # Store lines prefixed by number of words in line.
    # As numbers are fixed-length and zero-prefixed, an ASCII
    # sort will also be a numeric sort.
    a[NR] = sprintf("%04d%s", NF, $0)
}

END {
    # sort the stored lines
    asort(a)
    # strip off the prefix and print each line
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) {
        line = substr(a[i], 5)
        print(line)
    }
}
```

IMHO the Python is cleaner and easier to understand.  In Python you do have to explicitly read the arguments from the command line, while in AWK you don't; but in other ways I think the Python is easier to understand.

EDIT: So, here is the output.  Is this what you wanted?  I thought it was, but I just looked again at your example output and that isn't quite the same.  If your example is perfectly correct then I don't actually understand what you are trying to do.

This is what you get when you sort first by number of words and second by the words:

```
capital
capital is
capital of
capital is the
capital of the
capital is the like
capital of the country
```

Also, there was a bug in the AWK version and it didn't print the last line.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement the Schwartzian transform that steveha references using a pipeline

```
awk '{print NF, $0}' file.txt | sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -f2- -d' '
capital 
capital is 
capital of 
capital is the   
capital of the 
capital is the like 
capital of the country
```

OR all within [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), with callouts to `sort` and `cut`

```
awk '{print NF, $0 | "sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -f2- -d\\  "}' file.txt
```